# generating documentation with doxygen: encoding problems

Tags: ros, rosdoc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I try to generate the doxygen documentation of my C++ Code I get the error explained below. Does anybody know how to avoid this problem? Does this mean that my doxygen documentation on C++ files is bad-written? Thanks in advance

```
$ rosrun rosdoc rosdoc mypackage
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/src/rosdoc/rdcore.py:43: UserWarning: roslib.rospack is deprecated, please use rospkg
  import roslib.rospack
initializing rosdoc context:
    package filters: ['mypackage']
    path filters: []
+package[mypackage]
+stack[mystack]
ERROR: Doxygen of package [mypackage] failed: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
copying /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/templates/styles.css to doc/styles.css
copying /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/documentation/rosdoc/templates/msg-styles.css to doc/msg-styles.css
Timings
 * 0.00 epydoc
 * 0.00 support_files
 * 0.02 doxygen
 * 0.00 sphinx
 * 0.00 upload
 * 0.00 landing-page
 * 0.67 msg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48947/generating-documentation-with-doxygen:-encoding-problems/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2012-11-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I expect that this is a problem with unicode, or the lack there of, in the xml parsing. \xf1 is the ~n as in your name and I expect you used it in the author or maintainer field.  I'd try removing the character and trying again.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-12-14**:
That was the problem. I removed (sadly) the ñ in my name and worked.  Thanks! :-)